# Can we run multiple mule services/instances in one computer?

Tags: web-services, mule

We have two mule projects in different version 3.0 and 3.7. We want deploy these two projects in single VM (Windows). But I can able to run only one mule runtime not both in single VM(Windows).

Please advise!

Comment: Yes, we can run multiple mule services in one computer. I have some projects in mule version 3.5 (JDK 1.6) and 3.7 (JDK 8). All are running as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could run multiple esb instances on a single computer. we have experience doing that one 3.4 version and 3.7 version.